# launch phone app to make a call without number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is any body now if I can launch the phone app without number?? the user chose or wirte the   phone number to call?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:no number"]];
```

for launch the app phone call but no call with any number??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### App Store

Apple won't allow this — there's no point in launching the Phone app if there is no number to dial.

### Jailbreak

If you just want to launch the app without dialing a number, you can always launch the app via the bundle id. You will need to search around the net on how to do this.